# Refreshing progressbar in js

Tags: javascript, loops

**Hi,
im working on a progress bar in java script and i need it to reset it after it hits 100%.
Going infinetly.**

```
function start(al) {
    var bar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
    bar.value = al;
    al++;
    var sim = setTimeout("start(" + al + ")", 1);
    if (al == 100) {
      bar.value = 100;
      clearTimeout(sim);
    }
  }
  var amountLoaded = 0;
```

This works only if the page is refreshed. But it doesnt work automaticly.

Answer (score 0):

Using `setTimeout` with a string instead of using a callback is bad practice because it calls eval (making it a security risk) and is less readable. Also, instead of recursively calling `start` from your timeout callback, you can just use `setInterval`. From there you may increment your `bar.value` and check if the value is more than or equal to 100 to call `clearInterval`. Here, I used short circuiting for cleaner code, but you can expand it out to an if statement if you prefer.

```
function start(initialValue) {
    const bar = document.getElementById('progessBar');
    bar.value = initialValue;
    const sim = setInterval(() => ++bar.value >= 100 && clearInterval(sim), 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setInterval` to call your callback function that handles incrementing the `progressbar`.

If you want to reset the `progressbar` after an amount of time, you can use `setTimeout` to do so.

Here's a live demo that increments the `progressbar` by `10` every `500ms` and once it reaches `100%` the `setTimeout` method is used to reset the elemnt to `0` after `2s` from hitting `100%`:

```js
/** that function will automatically get executed (called an IIFE) */
(function start() {
  const bar = document.getElementById('progressBar'),
    percentage = document.getElementById('percentage')
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    /** tells whether the progress bar will be full after this iteration */
    const done = bar.value + 10 > 100;
    /** add 10 to the value */
    bar.value += 10;
    percentage.textContent = (done ? 100 : bar.value) + '%';
    /** 100% reached */
    if (done) {
      /** clear the interval so the callback function will no longer be called */
      clearInterval(interval);
      percentage.textContent = 'Resetting in 2 seconds...';
      /** add a 2s delay till resetting the progressbar */
      const timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
        bar.value = 0;
        percentage.textContent = '0%';
        clearTimeout(timeOut);
      }, 2000);
    }
  }, 500); /** the callback is invoked every 500ms */
})();
```

```html
<progress id="progressBar" max="100" value="0"></progress>
<span id="percentage">0%</span>
```

You can play around it and apply the values and/or conditions that suits you.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your responce!  This was very helpfull. It works, but do you know how to make it, that after the reset if will automatickly re call the funkcion ant the bra will load again and again after the reset? Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks i got it by adding another setInterval

Comment: @Samas111 Glad I managed to help you. If my answer was helpful, kindly set it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody in the future would be searching for this! Here is the code:

```
setInterval(function start() {
    const bar = document.getElementById('progressBar'),
        percentage = document.getElementById('percentage')
    interval = setInterval(() => {
        const done = bar.value + 10 > 100;
        bar.value += 10;
        percentage.textContent = (done ? 100 : bar.value) + '%';
        if (done) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        /** add a 2s delay till resetting the progressbar */
        const timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
            bar.value = 0;
            percentage.textContent = '0%';
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
        }, 100);
        }
    }, 80); /** @ths on stack overflow made this */
}, 1000)();
```

Html:

```
  <progress class="progressbar" id="progressBar" max="100" value="0"></progress>
<span id="percentage">0%</span>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).